# Animated GIF won't work on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, web-server, chromium, javascript

i'm building a local website that displays an animated GIF.

The website is opened using chromium web browser.

i'm sure that the GIF itself is working because I've tried to open it in different devices.

The thing is when i run the website , the GIF is not working.

The website show it like a regular static image.

Note: The code is JavaScript and the server I'm using is Apache

Comment: Where are you trying to load the gif? A browser on the RPi, or another?

Comment: @Jacobm001 A browser on the RPI.